# Docpad page generation from JSON Arrary or similar

Tags: json, code-generation, docpad

is there any way to configure DocPad to generate pages starting from a json array saved in external file (or inline string) instead of from a collection of files?

*To clarify, for show posts details I fetch from a JSON file, see below.*

instead of this:
`<% for post in @getCollection("html").findAll({ relativeOutDirPath: 'posts' }).toJSON(): %>`

I use this:
`<% for post in JSON.parse @include("posts.json"): %>`

Ok. Now I would to generate the post pages directly from this JSON and not creating a page for each post like in the example..

For example I would to create page with url /posts/{urlname}.html when {urlname} exist in JSON like this:

```
[
  { "id": "1", "urlname": "prod1", "metadata": { "title": "val1" } },
  { "id": "2", "metadata": null },
  { "id": "3", "urlname": "prod3", "metadata": { "title": "val1b", "prop2": "val2b" } }
]
```

I would to generate /posts/prod1.html and /posts/prod2.html page with metadata those in metadata properties..

Thank's for the replies.. ;)

***PS Great work!!!!!!!***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there is no official way to inject data into the DocPad in memory database besides having it parsed from the file system on the `src` directory (the way we are all use to). HOWEVER, this feature (called *importers*) is the next big todo for DocPad, you can find the [task issue here](https://github.com/bevry/docpad/issues/500).

For the meantime, you could include the JSON inside your [template data](http://docpad.org/docs/template-data), which is suitable for content listings, but not suitable for providing individual documents for each entry.

Comment: ok, thank's for the answer.

I'll watch on task issue page. ;)

Comment: Has this been implemented ? is there away to generate new pages from json ?

Comment: @balupton - is this now possible?

Comment: @SimonH besides the template data solution, one should just write a program to generate files that go into the `src` directory. Having DocPad import data from external databases without writing to the `src` directory is considered deprecated: https://discuss.bevry.me/t/deprecating-in-memory-docpad-importers-exporters/87?u=balupton